# magnific-popup basic implementation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magnific-popup

I am trying to implement the very basic example of magnific-popup ("Single image lightbox" in the official examples) on a page, but I can't get it to to work - when clicking on the thumbnail it just opens the fullsize image in the browser.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/magnific-popup.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        delegate: 'a',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        image: {
            verticalFit: true
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<a class="image-popup-vertical-fit" href="tbig.jpg">
    <img src="tsmall.jpg">
</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what might be going wrong? I don't see any error in the console.
I have added `delegate:'a'` to the script as per another topic, but it doesn't seem to help.
I suppose it's something pretty basic, but it really is eluding me...

Thanks!

Comment: If you remove the `delegate:'a'` it should work

Comment: nope, I tried without it at first and doesn't work either... I added afterwards only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `delegate:'a'` the following did not work. Without it I believe it does as you are expecting

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.js'></script>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
                    type:'image',   // no delegate:'a'
                    closeOnContentClick:true,
                    mainClass:'mfp-img-mobile',
                    image: { verticalFit:true }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <title>Magnific Popup</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='page'>
            <a class='image-popup-vertical-fit' href='//farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg'>
                <img src='//farm9.staticflickr.com/8242/8558295633_f34a55c1c6_s.jpg' width='150px' height='150px' />
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. Yes it works. And the difference is the linked magnific-popup js source... I was using an incomplete build from the built tool.

Comment: I'm glad that you have found the mistook and now have your code up & running!